# Single output type for interface function

Tags: java, function, interface, output

I am creating an interface like:

```
public interface InterfaceName {
    public [Object Type Undecided] functionName(String str1, String str2);
}
```

I will have functions implementing this interface as follows:

```
public class FunctionOne implements InterfaceName {

    @Override 
    public [Object Type Undecided] functionName(String str1, String st2) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

...

```
public class FunctionTwo implements InterfaceName {

    @Override 
    public [Object Type Undecided] functionName(String str1, String st2) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

In FunctionOne, I want the output to be an int, and in FunctionTwo, I want the output to be a Boolean. In later functions I'd like the output to be a String or some other type. What type of output should I make the "functionName" function?

Comment: The problem is vague, but I guess you should make your interface generic: `public interface InterfaceName<T> { T functionName(...) }`

Answer (score 0):

create an *interface* with a generic type e.g.

```
public interface InterfaceName<T> {
       T functionName(..., ...); 
}
```

Comment: Don't use the same symbol for unrelated generics parameters. Furthermore, the `<T>` in your interface return type renders the generic interface parameter `<T>` unused. Furthermore, making the method generic only on the return type limits how the compiler can infer the type. The generic parametrization of the method is unneeded and so is the complexity it adds.

Answer (score -1):

Let's use [generic type](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm)
Example:

```
public interface InterfaceName <T>{
    public T functionName(String str1, String str2);
}

public class FunctionOne <T> implements InterfaceName <T>{

    @Override 
    public T functionName(String str1, String st2) {
        // Code here
        return (T)(Integer) 1;
    }
}

public class FunctionTwo <T> implements InterfaceName <T> {

    @Override 
    public T functionName(String str1, String st2) {
        // Code here
        return (T)(Boolean.True);
    }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't compile, and it shows you haven't really understood the principle of generic types.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet for help, I have edited wrong syntax for it can work now

Comment: Now it compiles, but you still haven't understood the whole point of generic types. The point of having a generic List<T> is to be able to have List<Integer>, List<String>, List<Boolean>, etc. Your two classes are generic, and are supposed to return T, but they don't. They return an Integer or a Boolean, which will obviously cause a runtime exception if T is not Integer or Boolean.